# Pass data from android to flutter

Tags: flutter, native

I have added my Android side code:
I know that I need to use a platform channel to pass data,I am unable to figure out:

```
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button Btn;
   // Intent defaultFlutter=FlutterActivity.createDefaultIntent(activity);
    String path;
    private Button bt;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Btn = findViewById(R.id.btn);

        isStoragePermissionGranted();
       Btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


           @Override
           public void onClick(View view)
            {
                path=takeScreenshot();
               // activity.startActivity(defaultFlutter);
            }

        });
        //write flutter xode here
 //FlutterActivity.createDefaultIntent(this);

    }
    private String takeScreenshot() {
        Date now = new Date();
        android.text.format.DateFormat.format("yyyy-MM-dd_hh:mm:ss", now);

        try {
            // image naming and path  to include sd card  appending name you choose for file
            String mPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/" + now + ".jpg";

            // create bitmap screen capture
            View v1 = getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
            v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache());
            v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

            File imageFile = new File(mPath);
            Log.d("path",mPath);
            FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
            int quality = 100;
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, quality, outputStream);
            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.close();
            return mPath;
            ///openScreenshot(imageFile);
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            // Several error may come out with file handling or DOM

            e.printStackTrace();
            return "Error";
        }
    }
    public boolean isStoragePermissionGranted() {
        String TAG = "Storage Permission";
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
            if (this.checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Log.v(TAG, "Permission is granted");
                return true;
            } else {
                Log.v(TAG, "Permission is revoked");
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
                return false;
            }
        }
        else { //permission is automatically granted on sdk<23 upon installation
            Log.v(TAG,"Permission is granted");
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

I will receive a file from the android side, upon receiving I need to display it in a flutter. I also need to use cached engine for transferring data as normally it would cause a delay

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I want to pass from onCreate to Flutter

Answer (score 0):

You can use the cached engine, this will help me cover up for the delay.
Then you can add a invoke method onpressed that you can send method name and the data you want to pass.
On flutter side,you can create a platform and invoke method through which you can receive requirements and further process it,